# ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: oracle

I am getting data from erp systems in the form of feeds ,in particular one column length in feed is 15 only.

In target table also corresponded column also length is `varchar2(15)`  but when I am trying to load same into db it showing error like:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column emp_name (actual: 16, maximum:
>   15)

I cant increase the column length since it is base table in the production.

Comment: Are you saying: there are two tables, both have a varhcar2(15) column and when you insert the value from table1 into table2 you get the error?

Comment: If they are truly varchar2(15) - not nvarchar2, then your code is adding a character somehow.  What does the code sql look like (edit your post to add it).

Comment: It is simple insert statement like below 
insert into aaa (id,
site_id) select id,site_id from bbb where id in (select id from cc)

Comment: Ok -then there must be a language (NLS) session setting.  Do emp_name values have odd looking characters?

Comment: No it doesnot contains any odd looking characters.

Comment: Is your character set UTF-8?

Comment: even I tried with below query. which doent fetches any value/row
select * from bbb where length(site_id)>15;

Comment: in nls_database_parameters table parameter='NLS_LENGTH_SEMATICS' has value 'BYTE'.Do I need to change this to character.

Comment: Either I did not communicate well, or you are unaware of something.  Anyway, I have no idea as to the cause or how to fix it. IF you have two columns each with the same character set and same length, then it is not possible for one of them to suddenly add a character at random.

Comment: Yes NLS_CHARACTER is AL32UTF38

Comment: What language is that?  I cannot google that value.

Comment: Language is AMERICAN

Comment: Sorry if I sound grumpy, but in what ways is the answer you now marked as accepted better than my (previously accepted) answer? It just gives the same advice (`ALTER TABLE ... `), it doesn't contain any additional useful information and just contains an external link (which are discouraged on SO).

Comment: Why is this exception not thrown by hibernate so that we can handle it and send a custom message to client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

have a look into this blog, the problem resolved for me by changing the column datatype from varchar(100) to varchar(100 char). in my case the data contains some umlaut characters.

http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/byte_or_character

Answer (score 12):

The usual reason for problems like this are non-ASCII characters that can be represented with one byte in the original database but require two (or more) bytes in the target database (due to different NLS settings).

To ensure your target column is large enough for 15 characters, you can modify it:

```
  ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
```

(note the `15 CHAR` - you can also use `BYTE`; if neither is present, the database uses the  NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS setting as a default).

To check which values are larger than 15 bytes, you can

- create a staging table in the target database with the column length set to `15 CHAR`
- insert the data from the source table into the staging table
- find the offending rows with

  SELECT * FROM staging WHERE lengthb(mycol) > 15

(note the use of `LENGTHB` as apposed to `LENGTH` - the former returns the length in bytes, whereas the latter returns the length in characters)

Answer (score 0):

I found AL32UTF8 as the only valid setting.  This varies from standard UTF8 with a few character having supplementary bytes, i.e, the characters are about 99% the same.  I am guessing you have character conversion problems going on.  In other words the data in table1 was written using one charset, and the new table has a slightly different charset.

If this is true, you have to find the source of the oddball charset.  Because this will continue to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to:

> ORA-12899: VALUE TOO LARGE FOR COLUMN(ACTUAL,MAXIMUM)

If you are facing problem while updating a column size of a table which already has data more than the new length below is the simple script that would work definitely.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD (NEW_COLUMN_NAME DATATYPE(DATASIZE));
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NEW_COLUMN_NAME  = SUBSTR(OLD_COLUMN_NAME , 1, NEW_LENGTH);
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN OLD_COLUMN_NAME ;
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RENAME COLUMN NEW_COLUMN_NAME  TO OLD_COLUMN_NAME;
```

Meaning of the query:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD (NEW_COLUMN_NAME DATATYPE(DATASIZE));
```

It would just create a new column of the required new length in your existing table.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NEW_COLUMN_NAME  = SUBSTR(OLD_COLUMN_NAME , 1, NEW_LENGTH);
```

It will discard all the values after the new length value from old column values and set the trimmed values into the new column name.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN OLD_COLUMN_NAME ;
```

It will remove the old column name as its absurd now and we have copied all the information into the new column.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RENAME COLUMN NEW_COLUMN_NAME  TO OLD_COLUMN_NAME;
```

Renaming the new column name to the old column name would help you regain the original table structure except for the new column size as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the cause of error is that the value is too large for column data type. However, sometimes it is not visible at first sight. Except "byte versus char" differences mentioned in other answers, there can also be problem with line terminators.

I was trying to load CSV file using SQL*Loader in dockerized Oracle. The `foo` column of type `char(1)` was the last column. I got `ORA-12899: value too large for column foo (actual: 2, maximum: 1)` error despite all values of `foo` column were of length 1. Later I noticed the CSV file has been edited in Windows editor and accidentally saved with CRLF terminators. Since Linux in Docker container expects just LF, the CR was treated as part of column data.

Answer (score 0):

This error made me confused a little bit.

> VARCHAR2(x CHAR) means that the column will hold x characters but not
> more than can fit into 4000 bytes. Internally, Oracle will set the
> byte length of the column (DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_LENGTH) to MIN(x *
> mchw, 4000), where mchw is the maximum byte width of a character in
> the database character set. This is 1 for US7ASCII or WE8MSWIN1252, 2
> for JA16SJIS, 3 for UTF8, and 4 for AL32UTF8.
>
> For example, a VARCHAR2(3000 CHAR) column in an AL32UTF8 database will
> be internally defined as having the width of 4000 bytes. It will hold
> up to 3000 characters from the ASCII range (the character limit), but
> only 1333 Chinese characters (the byte limit, 1333 * 3 bytes = 3999
> bytes). A VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) column in an AL32UTF8 database will be
> internally defined as having the width of 400 bytes. It will hold up
> to any 100 Unicode characters.

Reference: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/421117/difference-between-varchar2-4000-byte-varchar2-4000-char